# Security implications of using CKEditor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ckeditor

I have just implemented CKEditor for rich text entry in my app and I am thinking that the ability of a user to enter anything could pose a security threat.

At the moment, I have the simplest implementation - CKEditor sits in a form, input is saved to the database as part of `update_attributes`, and other people can view the output as `html_safe`.

Somehow, the above doesn't sound good to me, even though it works. Am I correct in thinking there are risks to the above approach? Is there a safer way to do this to block an attack through the editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always take care of sanitizing a users input. In your case, by stripping all unwanted HTML tags (like , for example) regardless of where it came from.

`html_safe` is not meant to strip HTML or sanitize for you. See [Yehuda Katz' article](http://yehudakatz.com/2010/02/01/safebuffers-and-rails-3-0/) on [`ActiveSupport::SafeBuffer`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/SafeBuffer.html). It is meant to prevent "unsafe" markup by marking a String as safe, if it is (and encoding it to HTML entities otherwise, to make it safe).

There are sanitation helpers in [`ActionView::Helpers::SanitizeHelper`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html) that you can use to sanitize what is displayed, but you might want to sanitize it before it enters the database.

If you strip away the possibility of inserting CSS, Javascript or an iframe, you should be fine. If you're paranoid about what your users do, also take away `<img>` tags. And if you're really paranoid, you should consider using [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/), Textile or others.

Comment: Hi fx_ - thanks a lot for your response. I've got this in Application.rb: `config.action_view.sanitized_allowed_tags = %w(h1 h2 h3 h4 b i p u a pre div span br ul ol li em strong strike img)`. Does this, combined with `sanitize(@notes.body)` strip out CSS, JS, iframes, etc.?

Comment: _This sanitize helper will html encode all tags and strip all attributes that aren’t specifically allowed._ -- see [`ActionView::Helpers::SanitizeHelpers#sanitize`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper/sanitize)